# Adding folder and shortcut to Windows 10 Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I have Win10 and I’m trying to add a new folder to the start menu.
So under `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, I have created a new folder with a single shortcut to a program, but I still don’t see it in the start menu.

I have tried to restart the PC and restart a few processes.

Comment: Place a shortcut in the following ‘Hidden’ folder:
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

Comment: I can see the shortcut if I create it directly under C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs but if I add a sub folder ...\Start Menu\Programs\TEST I don't.see the shortcut nor the folder.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to see this shortcut on the `All Apps` list or on the `Start Menu`?  Also, is this shortcut designed to be available to everyone, or just yourself?  All of the above are possible, but creating a parent folder is probably unnecessary.  I usually create shortcuts to Recent Items on my Windows 10 machines using the method I described in my answer below.

Answer (score 15):

Rather than creating a new folder with a single shortcut, just copy the shortcut itself to the following location:

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Right-click that shortcut on the **All Apps** list and select `Pin to start`

Answer (score 2):

To create folder in Windows 10 Start Menu (for all user accounts) go to:

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

And just create new folder there. The folder you have just created will not immediately appear on the Start Menu. You must put at least one shortcut inside the folder and provided administrator permission to do that, the folder will then shows up on the Start Menu.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that to create a New folder in the Start menu, I had to create the same folder in the Start menu of "All users"and the user as I was logged in as!

Answer (score 0):

For those like me using Classic Shell, all I needed to do was to right-click on Programms and select Open.
From there, I could add a folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have to place apps in C:\somefolder\app.exe and make shortcut to it. If I used more nested folders like C:\folder1\folder2\app.exe , it did not work. Hallo mikrosoft.

Answer (score 0):

I read the question a bit differently so I will add the answer that helped me: I wanted to add a folder to the start menu *as a tile **folder***. So not just in the list of all programs, but a clickable tile that expands when pressed.

Here is how: follow the steps in [Run5k's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1167971/617663) to create a folder that will appear in the overall list of the start menu. Do not right-click to pin to start, this will simply create a shortcut to the folder (and open it in explorer). You can't drag that folder from the list to the tile section. Instead, drag the first element inside that folder (in my case, a shortcut) to the tile section. This will create a new tile. Then, drag the second item from the folder *on top of* the new tile. This will automatically create a tile-folder. Rinse & repeat for all elements of the folder.